# Maximum likelihood estimator. How can I deal with the indicator function?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Let $X$ a random variable with density function $f(x)=\theta x^{\theta -1}\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(x)$, with $\theta>0$ unknown.
I would like to compute the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$.

My idea is the following.
I write the likelihood function:
$$G(x_1, \cdots, x_n)=\theta^n\prod_{i=1}^nx_i  \mathbb I_{(0,1)}(x_i). $$
My problem is how to deal with the indicator function. Without it I would consider the $\log G$ and I would compute its derivative to see where it is equal to $0$. Doing this I find
$$\hat \theta=-n\sum_{i=1}^n\log x_i.$$

Is this correct? How can I deal with the indicator function?

@edit The maximum likelihood estimator I found, that is $\hat \theta=-n\sum_{i=1}^n\log x_i$ is not a sufficient statistics for $\theta$. Could someone telling me how I could find a sufficient statistics for $\theta$?

Thank you

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2649775/321264

Answer (score 1):

Recall
$$  \Bbb{I}_{(0,1)}(x_i) = \begin{cases} 1 ,& x_i \in (0,1) \\ 0 ,& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}  \text{.}  $$

Then \begin{align*}
\prod_{i=1}^n x_i \Bbb{I}_{(0,1)}(x_i) &= \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \prod_{i=1}^n \Bbb{I}_{(0,1)}(x_i)  \\
    &= \begin{cases} \prod_{i=1}^n x_i ,& \text{ all the $x_i \in (0,1)$}  \\  0,& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{align*}

The upshot is you get your $\hat{\theta}$ conditional on all the $x_i \in (0,1)$.